# Why are native English speakers convinced that English language is a Romance language?

Tags: latin, french, romance-languages, spanish, italian

Most people I've know so far in the USA are always saying that learning Latin would be really easy because, since English comes from Latin, it cannot be a hard thing to do, and they really get shocked when I reply that English is not a Romance language.

Why are so many native speakers of English convinced that English language is a Romance language?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is English classified as a Germanic rather than Romance language?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8342/why-is-english-classified-as-a-germanic-rather-than-romance-language)

Comment: This is a good illustration of the fact that Anglophone school systems don't teach students anything about their language. [They used to, at least the top ones did](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/1899MatriculationExam.pdf). But not any more.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how you define a Romance language.

Linguists consider what first makes a language is its grammar, its basic structure and rules. Under that point of view, English is definitely a Germanic language.

On the other hand, the average Joe, whatever its mother tongue, tend to consider the vocabulary to be the most important parameter to consider when defining a language. Using that metric, it is clear English is closer to French/Latin than say German, Dutch or Norwegian.

See https://medium.com/@andreas_simons/the-english-language-is-a-lot-more-french-than-we-thought-heres-why-4db2db3542b3

[image]

Comment: -1 because I don't like the source, making bold but unsubstantiated claims in an overconfident language.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica Merry Christmas too :-)

Comment: @ReinstateMonica can you offer specific criticisms of the medium article?  The author is not a linguist and he offers some non-mainstream views but his data seems valid (though his interpretation may not be).

Comment: One obvious criticism is that the percentage of core vocabulary is a far more important indicator than the percentage of vocabulary, and even the graph in this answer shows the first to be strongly dominated by Germanic words. But I'm not a linguist either, so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: @DenisNardin The author of the source states that "core vocabulary" isn't strictly defined but the consensus is between 3k to 5k most common words used. This chart then accurately shows that core English, doesn't it?

Comment: @DenisNardin FWIW 73% of the substantives used in your comment are of French or Latin origin (Germanic, criticism, dominated, grain, graph, important, indicator, linguist, obvious, percentage, vocabulary vs answer, core, salt, words). On the other hand, all non substantives (verbs, articles, adjectives, adverbs...) are Germanic.